# Why the Qt(4.8) serial port(qextserialport) readind data from device in 2 part?

Tags: c++, qt, embedded-linux, qextserialport

this is my code : (I used qextserialport)

```
SerialPort::SerialPort(QString port)
{
    sp=new QextSerialPort;
    sp->setPortName(port);
    /*port->setBaudRate(BAUD9600);
    port->setFlowControl(FLOW_OFF);
    port->setParity(PAR_NONE);
    port->setDataBits(DATA_8);
    port->setStopBits(STOP_2);*/
    sp->setBaudRate(BAUD115200);
    sp->setDataBits(DATA_8);
    sp->setFlowControl(FLOW_OFF);
    sp->setParity(PAR_NONE);
    sp->setStopBits(STOP_1);
    sp->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    connect(sp,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(ReadData()));

}

void SerialPort::ReadData()
{
    QByteArray ba;
    ba.resize(512);
    ba=sp->readAll();
    emit DataRecieve(ba);
}
```

this code run on Ubuntu at first and show all the bytes which receive from device, but when I tested it in linux embedded device this code read data from serial device in 2 part. () there is no \n in my bytes.
I change the code to this code :

```
void SerialPort::ReadData()
{
    QByteArray ba;
    ba.resize(512);
    if(sp->bytesAvailable()>0 || sp->waitForReadyRead(20000))
    {
    qDebug()<<sp->bytesAvailable();
    ba=sp->readAll();
    qDebug()<<ba.toHex();
    emit DataRecieve(ba);
    }
}
```

but again my output is :

```
4 "aa5524010400000000000000"   
12 "000000000000000000002801"
```

but it should be :

```
"aa5524010400000000000000000000000000000000002801"
```

My output size is maybe 48 bytes or 512 bytes

Comment: What is the serial buffer size of your device?

Comment: I think 512. because the biggest data that can send is 512 bytes

Comment: What device is it?

Comment: CAMA series finger print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on serial port driver buffer.  You can got `readyRead()` signal on one ready byte, for example.
You should save received bytes to intermediate buffer and process it after all.